# store value access in Ext template in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 field in store 1. title and 2. active boolean value.

I have below ext.template

```
itemTpl : Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                 '<div style = "height:5px; border-top: 0px solid #DEDEDE;">',
                    '<div style="float:left" >',
                        '<input type ="image" src="images/sort-ascending-default.png" id = "img1"  name ="img1" width="30px" height="30px" />',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div  class="itemTitle" id="itemTitle" style="float:left;width: 70%;height: 20px;text-align: center;  color :#fffff0;">{title}</div>',
                    '<div style="float:right;  vertical-align:middle;">',
                        '<input type ="image" src="images/sort-descending-default.png" id = "img2" name ="img2" width="30px" height="30px"/>',
                    '</div>',
                    '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
                 '</div>'),
```

I want to put if condition in it and want to check active field and change the color of title but I don't know how to access the store field value.

Comment: Plenty of conditional processing examples here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can use if condition in tpl:

```
itemTpl : Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
             '<div style = "height:5px; border-top: 0px solid #DEDEDE;">',
                '<div style="float:left" >',
                    '<input type ="image" src="images/sort-ascending-default.png" id = "img1"  name ="img1" width="30px" height="30px" />',
                '</div>',
                '<tpl if="active == true">',
                    '<div  class="itemTitle" id="itemTitle" style="float:left;width: 70%;height: 20px;text-align: center;  color :red;">{title}</div>',
                '<tpl else>',
                    '<div  class="itemTitle" id="itemTitle" style="float:left;width: 70%;height: 20px;text-align: center;  color :green;">{title}</div>',
                '</tpl>'
                '<div style="float:right;  vertical-align:middle;">',
                    '<input type ="image" src="images/sort-descending-default.png" id = "img2" name ="img2" width="30px" height="30px"/>',
                '</div>',
                '<div style="clear:both"></div>',
             '</div>'),
```